# Sum col2 of two tables based on duplicate matching col1

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have 2 tables both structured as (id, views)

```
Table 1:
id  views
A   1
B   2
B   3
C   3
C   4
D   4

Table 2:
id  views
C   1
D   3
D   4
E   5
E   7
F   8
```

I'm looking to sum views of ids that are both in table 1 and 2 (id C and D) in this case so the output would be:

```
Table 3:
id  views
C   8
D   11
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following query in your case :

```
select a.id,sum(a.views) from ( select * from table1 union table2 ) as a group by id;
```

Comment: Doesn't the union just get rid of the duplicate values and still include the views from ids that weren't duplicated between both tables (A, B, E, F)?

Answer (score 0):

select id,sum(views) from (select * from table1 union all select * from table2)a where a.id="C" or a.id="D" group by id;